# Facebook Sharer and page Authentication

Tags: php, facebook-sharer

The website I am developing requires authentication before you can access anything, but I want to allow users to share information with facebook once they have logged in. When I use the standard facebook sharer.php link it pulls up the data from the login page, not the page with the data the user would want to share.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content>
```

Is there any way to allow Facebook to see the data behind the authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary work around:

[http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=178614]

In the last post on this page the user talks about how he used static pages with redirects so that the facebook sharer would find the proper data, and the user would be redirected to the page they expected. Doesn't seem to be the best way, but it works for now.